# Implement singleTap and doubleTap in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I add singTap and doubleTap to a view like the code below:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    //
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTapGesture:)];
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
}

-(void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)singleTapGesture{
    [[self delegate] singleTapOnView];
}

-(void)handleDoubleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)doubleTapGesture{
    [[self delegate] doubleTapOnView];
}
```

When doubleTap the singleTap also fire. How to disable singleTap when doubleTap? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tell the single-tap recognizer that it requires the double-tap recognizer to fail before it triggers:

```
[singleTapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapGesture];
```

(This is actually the canonical example in the [UIGestureRecognizer docs for this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW36).)